# Array of string php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm tring to create an array of string but I can't do this if I use a variable.

```
$dir_photo="./Foto_NEW/";
$photo= array($dir_photo+"DSCN2507.JPG",$dir_photo+"IMG_0054.JPG",$dir_photo+"IMG_0058.JPG");
```

The result is 0 0 0.

Comment: The concatenation operator is `.` in PHP. Not `+`.

Comment: @StefanoMaglione: It happens! Everyone was a beginner once :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` is the concatenation operator in Javascript, but in PHP it's the period `.` So what you need is this:

```
$photo= array($dir_photo."DSCN2507.JPG",$dir_photo."IMG_0054.JPG",$dir_photo."IMG_0058.JPG");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the `+` with a `.`

```
$dir_photo."DSCN2507.JPG"
```

`+` is used in javascript, `.` is used in php

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$dir_photo="./Foto_NEW/";
$photo= array($dir_photo."DSCN2507.JPG",$dir_photo."IMG_0054.JPG",$dir_photo."IMG_0058.JPG");
```

You need to use `.` instead of `+` to concatenate strings.